# Can a locked row [in Postgres] still be read from?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transaction-isolation

If I `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` a row in a transaction, it will obviously block the row from being written to, but will it disallow reads as well? I'd prefer to still be able to read from the row, so if the answer is yes, can you provide a solution to work this?

Comment: I imagine if you can't, you'll have to use `READ UNCOMMITTED`

Comment: @OMGPonies: Postgres - like many other DBMS - does **not** allow read uncommitted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: [SQL Server does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx), at transaction or table level (though the optimizer can ignore it depending on criteria).  [Oracle supports READ UNCOMMITTED](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html)...

Comment: @OMGPonies: I know that SQL Server violates the ACID principle if asked for. But that's about the only one out there if I'm not mistaken. In my eyes it's a dirty workaround for not having proper (i.e. transactionally safe) non-blocking reads

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sybase ASE also supports `READ UNCOMMITTED` (which is not surprising considering that MS SQL Server is derived from it), and I have actually had to use it. We brought up a web site that was read-only, where queries tended to be from a table down a bit in the schema structure, while the replication was happening as on the source, from the top down.  Deadlocks galore.  We had to change all indexes to `UNIQUE` (by adding any missing PK columns) and use RU isolation. MVCC databases are much nicer in this regard, no need to degrade isolation level.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can read just fine. There are lock modes that prevent reading but this isn't one of them.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html

Comment: Excellent, thanks - And, of course this is the exact answer I was hoping for!

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more. Answered the question with no prevarication.

Comment: Just eye-balling this a little more. Pure `SELECT` statements do not block reads, but another concurrent `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` operation **will** block until the first `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` transaction completes.

Comment: You've explicitly asked for a lock on all the rows returned then though, haven't you? It wouldn't make any sense to return the rows *before* you knew you could gain the lock on them.